# Count total in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I trying to send an email summary to show how many the total of files that are empty or Full in my table records as shown in the query. My question is how do I create a counter for the total empty/full files and then the total number of both! Any help would be much appreciated

```
 // Connection String 
            string ConnectionString = @"Data Source= (localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=Database; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;";
            SqlDataReader reader;
            String SendMessage = "Select * FROM  Files where Full = 1 or Empty = 2";
            using (SqlConnection MyCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                MyCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, MyCon);
                ArrayList EmailArray = new ArrayList();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var Email = new List<EmailSend>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    Email.Add(new EmailSend
                    {


                        Full = Convert.ToString(reader["Full"]),
                        Empty = Convert.ToString(reader["Empty"]),

                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with just doing this in the sql?

```
string SendMessage = @"
            SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files where Full = 1 ) AS CountFull, 
                   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Files where Empty = 2) AS CountEmpty"
```

Then replace `while(reader.Read())` loop with

```
int countFull=-1,countEmpty =-1;

if(reader.Read())
{
 countFull = (int)reader["CountFull"];
 countEmpty = (int)reader["CountEmpty"];
}

int fullOrEmpty = countFull+countEmpty;
```

Comment: Why are you initializing the integers as -1? Should be 0 I think. You shouldn't be relying on a negative integer to indicate an error or state.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers